# Erasing blank spaces from columns in a database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datagridview that shows one table from my sql but it has some blankspaces as you can see in this screenshot:

[image]

And I was wondering if it's possible to remove those blank spaces. I have already tried this:

```
SqlCommand objcmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.UXMenu SET TransDocument = 
RTRIM(TransDocument) WHERE Estado = 0", myConnection);
objcmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But instead of removing the blank spaces it removes the entire row.

Here is my code for display the data in the datagridview, if you want more details about the code feel free to ask.

```
InitializeComponent();
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data source = ****;Database=****; User Id=****; Password=****");
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand objcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT TransDocument, TransSerial, 
TransDocNumber, PartyName, PartyLocalityID, TotalAmount, ShipToPostalCode FROM dbo.UXMenu WHERE Estado = 0", myConnection);
objcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(objcmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adp.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = 
DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I added the code that I use to create the table

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXMenu', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXMenu(TransDocument char(5), TransSerial char(5), TransDocNumber float  PRIMARY KEY, PartyName char(60), PartyLocalityID char(5), TotalAmount char (25), ShipToPostalCode char(35), Estado int);", myConnection);
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Added the code that creates the textfile

```
if (dataGridViewEnviarDados.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
 foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridViewEnviarDados.SelectedRows)
  {
   var transactionHandler = new TransactionHandler();
   FileInfo arquivo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\HP8200\Desktop\faturas\" + r.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + r.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + r.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + ".txt");                    
     using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(arquivo.FullName, false, Encoding.Default))
    {
      foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridViewEnviarDados.Columns)
    {
     tw.Write(r.Cells[c.Name].Value.ToString() + ";");
    }
    tw.Close();
  }
 }
}
```

**UPDATE 3:**

Changed my code to this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXMenu', 'U') IS NULL CREATE TABLE UXMenu(TransDocument varchar(5), TransSerial varchar(5), TransDocNumber float  PRIMARY KEY, PartyName varchar(60), PartyLocalityID varchar(5), TotalAmount varchar(25), ShipToPostalCode varchar(35), Estado int);", conn);
```

And now my table look like this:

[image]

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (E.g. RTRIM is product specific.)

Comment: i can't see blank spaces in this screenshot.

Comment: @Whencesoever E.g. In between TransDocument and TransSeries there are a lot of blank spaces

Comment: @jarlh what do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean that the columns are too wide?

Comment: @Jerodev yes, because I need to write a textfile from this data and those blank spaces add spaces in the textfile

Comment: Please post your code that creates the text file, because the width of your columns should not affect this.

Comment: Change data types of columns from `char` to `varchar` in your table.

Comment: @Rokuto did that, check the question last update

Comment: Great. Did you try to run it?

Comment: Yes, and added a screenshot on how my datagridview looks like

Comment: And...? Try to save it to textfile, because there is a problem, not in datagridview. If there are still whitespaces, you have to change data type of all `char` columns in your EXISTING table.

Comment: @Rokuto i'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to change my `chars` to `varchar` and did something like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("IF OBJECT_ID('UXMenu', 'U') IS
 NULL CREATE TABLE UXMenu(TransDocument varchar(5), TransSerial
 varchar(5), TransDocNumber float  PRIMARY KEY, PartyName varchar(60),
 PartyLocalityID varchar(5), TotalAmount varchar(25), ShipToPostalCode
 varchar(35), Estado int);", conn);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `char` datatype - this will create a column that is *always* that length, so by doing `char(35)` you are saying "create me a column that is 35 chars wide, even if i only put 2 characters in it".

You probably want `varchar` which is a variable character length field.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try this

Comment: Use nvarchar if multi-lingual database.

Comment: What am i checking..?

Comment: @Josue Figueiredo ,Please specify your table's columns with datatype and size in a database